# Columns in foreach GridMvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, grid.mvc

I'm using [Grid.MVC](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/documentation) to display data

I would like to create dynamic column within my grid
In my view i display the column as follow

I'm passing `IEnumerable<Student>`

**RAZOR**

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Add(c => c.Name).SetWidth(30).Titled("Student Name");

    // i want to add for loop here to disply extra columns know at runtime
    // the following doesn't work (want to replace ?? with
    foreach (var task in ??.StudentTasks)
    {
        columns.Add(task.StudentSubject.Code).SetWidth(30).Titled("code"+uniq);
    }
}
```

**.CS**

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<StudentTask> StudentTasks { get; set; }
}

public class StudentTask
{
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
    public Subject StudentSubject { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the Model being passed into your razor?  Without this there isn't enough info to answer.  Also, separate the razor and .cs for clarity.

Comment: I'm passing `IEnumerable<Student>`

Comment: Is your goal to display a column for any unique StudentTask?  If so you would want to pass the list of unique column names in addition to IEnumerable<Student> in your Model (a view model).

Comment: Column names not the issue here, i just want to dynamically Create columns based on number of StudentTask for each student

Comment: I understand that -- are you saying a different number of columns for each student?  Because I don't think that will work.  If you mean adding all the unique columns for all students then see my previous response.

Comment: Yes, different number of columns for each student
for example some students will have 3 tasks columns other 4 and other 7 etc.

Comment: Alright, I may be wrong, I don't think you can do that with a MVC.Grid.  You could make the columns generic and list the StudentTasks, or list all of the StudentTasks, but I don't think you can add columns per row.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this,if so please do share.